# How to access table's last column in pure javascript or typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular8

Tried to access last column for each row in pure javascript not in jquery but not working.Anyone know please help to find the solution.

app.component.html:

```
<div id="contentId">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td><select><option>Select</option><option value="test1">Test 1</option><option value="test2">Test 2</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td><select><option>Select</option><option value="test1">Test 1</option><option value="test2">Test 2</option></select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td><select><option>Select</option><option value="test1">Test 1</option><option value="test2">Test 2</option></select></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-jyxytf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: What is the use case and why don't you define a change event listener directly on the `select` element? `<select (change)="getEvent($event)">`

Comment: @uminder: Please do not change html. Can you do in ts file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want it in pure javascript way while you use angular,

Anyhow I am able to make a solution for you in pure javascript way with [dom querySelector() methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) ..

```
ngOnInit(){

  const gettable = document.getElementById("contentId").querySelector('table');
  const rows = gettable.getElementsByTagName('tr');

  for (let i=0; i<rows.length; i++)
  {
    const columns = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
    const lastColumn = columns[columns.length - 1];
    const select = lastColumn.querySelector('select');
    select.addEventListener('change', this.getEvent.bind(this, select))
  }

}

getEvent(selectedItem){  
  console.log(selectedItem.value);
  return event;
}
```

I have made a solution to retrieve each select box value at last of each row on selection..

[**Forked Stackblitz here ...**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-3qdsww)

**Update:**

If you are using primeng table and if you need to retrieve the value from the table (`p-table`), You can use angular [**elementRef**](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and get the value using,

```
const table = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('p-table table');
```

And the table will gets initialized completely inside [**ngAfterviewInit**](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) lifecycle hook hence changed from `ngOnInit()` hook.

Also added `ChangeDetectionStrategy` to detect changes on select box value(s)..

Updated stackblitz with primeng: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-ubgkcm**

Comment: I have one more question: Actually my table parent is like this <p-table id="contentId">....So can i use like this :  document.getElementById("p-table > contentId").querySelector('table') ??

Comment: Can you post the sample code using ```<p-table id="contentId">``` ?? Or provide some stackblitz link with the code.. I will look into it..

Comment: Please wait 2min

Comment: This is my stackblitz:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-zrsqh6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @NilaVaani, There is a complexity in achieving this way.. May I know the reason why you are not changing anything in template (HTML) ??

Comment: Anyhow I have made the things with the help of ```ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush``` ... I have modified the ```.ts``` file with inclusion of  ```ElementRef``` and ```ChangeDetectionStrategy```.. Changed  lifecycle from```ngOnInit``` to ```ngAfterViewInit()``` .. And few modification to my existing code has been done..

Comment: Look at the new example with primeng table sample and your expectations implemented here https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tables-ubgkcm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to install an event `change` listener on the `select` element contained in the last `td` element of each row, you could do the following:

```
ngOnInit(){ 
    const table: HTMLTableElement = document.getElementById("contentId").querySelector('table');
    Array.from(table.getElementsByTagName('tr')).map(tr => tr.querySelector('td:last-of-type').querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', event => this.getEvent(event)));
}
```

Please have a look at the forked [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/amexio-breadcrumb-demo-andpkc)